# Could someone explain to me the type returns in container_of?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Could someone explain to me these two macros?

```
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({            \
 const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
 (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

I understand everything except why offset_of is of (size_t) and container_of has (char *)?

How would (char *) -(size_t)  work in this macro?

I would have expected both of them to be of the same type. like char * for example.

Comment: I have no idea how this doesn't crash.  But `(char *) - size_t' is just a pointer decrement. When `p` is a pointer, `p-4` decrements `p` by `4*sizeof(*p)` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the value returned by offsetof is NOT a pointer. As the name suggests it's an offset of a field in given object. It is in bytes. size_t looks like an excellent type to hold the value.

Pointer arithmetic in c is trivial: p + n moves p by sizeof(*p). E.g. if p points to an object of size 8, p + 1 moves it by 8 so that it points to the next object.

char is **by definition** 1, hence all pointer arithmetic on char * pointers moves by 1. Thus it got employed here to move exactly by the amount obtained from offsetof.

Comment: Why doesn't this crash? Is the reason because its in a macro and the null derefrence is optimized away?

Comment: you mean the (type *)0)->member bit? there is no deference here. typeof is a magic compiler macro to get the type and the (type *)0 bit is just a crap syntax to get to the member.

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to `((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER`. If I call `offsetof(struct sockaddr, sa_family)` does this not cast `NULL` to a `struct sockaddr *` and then derefrence it BEFORE taking the address of `sa_family`? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: that one is &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER. note the ampersand - it does not deference anything, but takes the address. the address is computed by taking the value of the pointer (here 0) and adding to it.

Comment: I guess I disagree. Due to precedence the `&` is applied *after* the `->`. That's how it can get the offset from 0. Otherwise it would be `&((TYPE *) 0)` which would attempt to take the address of a literal.

Comment: well yes, it is the address of the field in the obj as pointed to by 0. 0 is not *followed* to compute the address.